# Animated model from 3Ds Max doesn't perfom animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3dsmax

I have some 3D model which was created in 3Ds Max with embedded animation.
After importing this model to Unity 3D it doesn't perform the animation.

Is there any method or property of this model to run animation?

Comment: is your model an fbx?

Comment: Yeah, fbx. Actualy it's not my model but my son's. I'm as interpreter here :-), he doesn't speak English yet.

Comment: Ok, I just posted an answer that is usually the problem with this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on the model in the project view, it should open up some import options in the inspector. One of the tabs is called "Rig". Try changing animation type to Legacy.